# Does anyone have any idea how to create a 2D skeleton with the Kinect depthmap?

Tags: kinect

I'm currently using a Processing Kinect library which supplies a depth map. I was wondering how I could take that and use it to create a 2D skeleton, if possible. Not looking for any code here, just a general process I could use to achieve those results.

Also, given that we've seen this in several of the Kinect games so far, would it be difficult to have multiple skeletons running at once?

Comment: google openNI and kinect, it has it built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** the reason why you still didn't get an answer for this question is probably because that's a current research problem. So I can't give you a direct answer but will try to help with some information and useful resources for this topic.

---

There are mainly 2 different approaches to create a skeleton from a depth map. The first one is to use machine learning, the second is purely algorithmic.

For the machine learning one, you'd need many samples of people doing a predetermined move, and use those samples to train your favorite learning algorithm. That's the approach that was taken and implemented by Microsoft in the XBox ([source](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/events/fs2010/presentations/Kudo_Fitzgibbons_Kinect_for_Xbox360_071210_FacSummit.pdf)), it works really well BUT you need millions of samples to make it reliable... quite a drawback.

The "algorithmic" approach (understand without using a training set) can be done in many different ways and is a research problem. It's often based on modeling the possible body postures and trying to match that with the depth image received. That's the approach that was chosen by PrimeSense (the guys behind the kinect depth camera technology) for their skeleton tracking tool NITE.

The [OpenKinect community](http://openkinect.org/) maintains a wiki where they list some [interesting research material](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Research_Material) about this topic. You might also be interested in [this thread on the OpenNI mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/7ce6b128743c76a9/215d4467204c135f?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Skeleton+tracking+algorithm%3A+theoretical+basis#215d4467204c135f).

If you're looking for an implementation of a skeleton tracking tool, PrimeSense released NITE (**closed** source), the one they made: it's part of the [OpenNI framework](http://www.openni.org/). That's what's used in most of the videos you might have seen that involve skeleton tracking. I think it's able to handle up to 2 skeletons at the same time, but that requires confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use FAAST (http://projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/faast/) which requires OpenNI.  I have struggled to get OpenNI to work on my computer.  I have not seen an approach yet using Code Laboratories' CL NUI.

Comment: This sounds good, but I'm running OSX so I don't think it's an option.

Comment: Yes, it is an option.The Wekinator project works on OSX.  It doesn't provide a skeleton but applies machine learning on the depth map for applications that might otherwise require the skeleton.

Comment: ... instead of FAAST use https://github.com/Sensebloom/OSCeleton#readme on the OpenNI/NITE framework.  OpenNI/NITE have OSX binaries.  See http://c4c.posterous.com/installing-openni-kinect-drivers-and-nite-on.  For some links make sure you scroll to the bottom of the page to find the OSX files.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithmic approach is http://code.google.com/p/skeletonization/ but you may have a problem because your depthmap only represents surfaces and no closed objects.